# ImportJSON Google Script trims the first row

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code is the script I am running in Google Sheets and the second code is the JSON file I am parsing.  The problem is that the first row of the JSON file always gets trimmed off.  Here is the command I am running in Google sheets:

```
=ImportJSON("http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/draft-projections/json/test/QB/", "", "")
```

Here is the Google Script ImportJSON.gs

```
 /*====================================================================================================================================*
  ImportJSON by Trevor Lohrbeer (@FastFedora)
  ====================================================================================================================================
  Version:      1.2.1
  Project Page: http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json
  Copyright:    (c) 2012-2013 by Trevor Lohrbeer
  License:      GNU General Public License, version 3 (GPL-3.0) 
                http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  A library for importing JSON feeds into Google spreadsheets. Functions include:

     ImportJSON            For use by end users to import a JSON feed from a URL 
     ImportJSONViaPost     For use by end users to import a JSON feed from a URL using POST parameters
     ImportJSONAdvanced    For use by script developers to easily extend the functionality of this library

  Future enhancements may include:

   - Support for a real XPath like syntax similar to ImportXML for the query parameter
   - Support for OAuth authenticated APIs (see AddOAuthService__ function for failed experiment)

  Or feel free to write these and add on to the library yourself!
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Changelog:

  1.2.1  Fixed a bug with how nested arrays are handled. The rowIndex counter wasn't incrementing properly when parsing.
  1.2.0  Added ImportJSONViaPost and support for fetchOptions to ImportJSONAdvanced
  1.1.1  Added a version number using Google Scripts Versioning so other developers can use the library
  1.1    Added support for the noHeaders option
  1.0    Initial release
 *====================================================================================================================================*/
/**
 * Imports a JSON feed and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is flattened to create 
 * a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to that data in 
 * the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data. 
 * 
 * By default, data gets transformed so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
 *
 *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
 *      of the rows representing their parent elements.
 *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
 *   - Headers have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title case. 
 *
 * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
 *
 *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
 *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
 *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
 *    noHeaders:     Don't include headers, only the data
 *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *   =ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", "/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content",
 *               "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
 * 
 * @param {url}          the URL to a public JSON feed
 * @param {query}        a comma-separated list of paths to import. Any path starting with one of these paths gets imported.
 * @param {parseOptions} a comma-separated list of options that alter processing of the data
 *
 * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
 **/
function ImportJSON(url, query, parseOptions) {
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, null, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}

/**
 * Imports a JSON feed via a POST request and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is 
 * flattened to create a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to 
 * that data in the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data.
 *
 * To retrieve the JSON, a POST request is sent to the URL and the payload is passed as the content of the request using the content 
 * type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If the fetchOptions define a value for "method", "payload" or "contentType", these 
 * values will take precedent. For example, advanced users can use this to make this function pass XML as the payload using a GET 
 * request and a content type of "application/xml; charset=utf-8". For more information on the available fetch options, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app . At this time the "headers" option is not supported.
 * 
 * By default, the returned data gets transformed so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
 *
 *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
 *     of the rows representing their parent elements.
 *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
 *   - Headers have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title case. 
 *
 * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
 *
 *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
 *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
 *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
 *    noHeaders:     Don't include headers, only the data
 *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *   =ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", "user=bob&apikey=xxxx", 
 *               "validateHttpsCertificates=false", "/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
 * 
 * @param {url}          the URL to a public JSON feed
 * @param {payload}      the content to pass with the POST request; usually a URL encoded list of parameters separated by ampersands
 * @param {fetchOptions} a comma-separated list of options used to retrieve the JSON feed from the URL
 * @param {query}        a comma-separated list of paths to import. Any path starting with one of these paths gets imported.
 * @param {parseOptions} a comma-separated list of options that alter processing of the data
 *
 * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
 **/
function ImportJSONViaPost(url, payload, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions) {
  var postOptions = parseToObject_(fetchOptions);

  if (postOptions["method"] == null) {
    postOptions["method"] = "POST";
  }

  if (postOptions["payload"] == null) {
    postOptions["payload"] = payload;
  }

  if (postOptions["contentType"] == null) {
    postOptions["contentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  }

  convertToBool_(postOptions, "validateHttpsCertificates");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "useIntranet");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "followRedirects");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "muteHttpExceptions");

  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, postOptions, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}

/**
 * An advanced version of ImportJSON designed to be easily extended by a script. This version cannot be called from within a 
 * spreadsheet.
 * 
 * Imports a JSON feed and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is flattened to create 
 * a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to that data in 
 * the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data. 
 *
 * The fetchOptions can be used to change how the JSON feed is retrieved. For instance, the "method" and "payload" options can be 
 * set to pass a POST request with post parameters. For more information on the available parameters, see 
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app .
 *
 * Use the include and transformation functions to determine what to include in the import and how to transform the data after it is
 * imported. 
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *   ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", 
 *              new Object() { "method" : "post", "payload" : "user=bob&apikey=xxxx" },
 *              "/feed/entry",
 *              "",
 *              function (query, path) { return path.indexOf(query) == 0; },
 *              function (data, row, column) { data[row][column] = data[row][column].toString().substr(0, 100); } )
 *
 * In this example, the import function checks to see if the path to the data being imported starts with the query. The transform 
 * function takes the data and truncates it. For more robust versions of these functions, see the internal code of this library.
 *
 * @param {url}           the URL to a public JSON feed
 * @param {fetchOptions}  an object whose properties are options used to retrieve the JSON feed from the URL
 * @param {query}         the query passed to the include function
 * @param {parseOptions}  a comma-separated list of options that may alter processing of the data
 * @param {includeFunc}   a function with the signature func(query, path, options) that returns true if the data element at the given path
 *                        should be included or false otherwise. 
 * @param {transformFunc} a function with the signature func(data, row, column, options) where data is a 2-dimensional array of the data 
 *                        and row & column are the current row and column being processed. Any return value is ignored. Note that row 0 
 *                        contains the headers for the data, so test for row==0 to process headers only.
 *
 * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
 **/
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}

/** 
 * Encodes the given value to use within a URL.
 *
 * @param {value} the value to be encoded
 * 
 * @return the value encoded using URL percent-encoding
 */
function URLEncode(value) {
  return encodeURIComponent(value.toString());  
}

/**
 * Adds an oAuth service using the given name and the list of properties.
 *
 * @note This method is an experiment in trying to figure out how to add an oAuth service without having to specify it on each 
 *       ImportJSON call. The idea was to call this method in the first cell of a spreadsheet, and then use ImportJSON in other
 *       cells. This didn't work, but leaving this in here for further experimentation later. 
 *
 *       The test I did was to add the following into the A1:
 *  
 *           =AddOAuthService("twitter", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
 *                            "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", 
 *                            "<my consumer key>", "<my consumer secret>", "", "")
 *
 *       Information on obtaining a consumer key & secret for Twitter can be found at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth
 *
 *       Then I added the following into A2:
 *
 *           =ImportJSONViaPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=fastfedora&count=2", "",
 *                              "oAuthServiceName=twitter,oAuthUseToken=always", "/", "")
 *
 *       I received an error that the "oAuthServiceName" was not a valid value. [twl 18.Apr.13]
 */
function AddOAuthService__(name, accessTokenUrl, requestTokenUrl, authorizationUrl, consumerKey, consumerSecret, method, paramLocation) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);

  if (accessTokenUrl != null && accessTokenUrl.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(accessTokenUrl);
  }

  if (requestTokenUrl != null && requestTokenUrl.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(requestTokenUrl);
  }

  if (authorizationUrl != null && authorizationUrl.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(authorizationUrl);
  }

  if (consumerKey != null && consumerKey.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  }

  if (consumerSecret != null && consumerSecret.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  }

  if (method != null && method.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setMethod(method);
  }

  if (paramLocation != null && paramLocation.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setParamLocation(paramLocation);
  }
}

/** 
 * Parses a JSON object and returns a two-dimensional array containing the data of that object.
 */
function parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var headers = new Array();
  var data    = new Array();

  if (query && !Array.isArray(query) && query.toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
    query = query.toString().split(",");
  }

  if (options) {
    options = options.toString().split(",");
  }

  parseData_(headers, data, "", {rowIndex: 1}, object, query, options, includeFunc);
  parseHeaders_(headers, data);
  transformData_(data, options, transformFunc);

  return hasOption_(options, "noHeaders") ? (data.length > 1 ? data.slice(1) : new Array()) : data;
}

/** 
 * Parses the data contained within the given value and inserts it into the data two-dimensional array starting at the rowIndex. 
 * If the data is to be inserted into a new column, a new header is added to the headers array. The value can be an object, 
 * array or scalar value.
 *
 * If the value is an object, it's properties are iterated through and passed back into this function with the name of each 
 * property extending the path. For instance, if the object contains the property "entry" and the path passed in was "/feed",
 * this function is called with the value of the entry property and the path "/feed/entry".
 *
 * If the value is an array containing other arrays or objects, each element in the array is passed into this function with 
 * the rowIndex incremeneted for each element.
 *
 * If the value is an array containing only scalar values, those values are joined together and inserted into the data array as 
 * a single value.
 *
 * If the value is a scalar, the value is inserted directly into the data array.
 */
function parseData_(headers, data, path, state, value, query, options, includeFunc) {
  var dataInserted = false;

  if (Array.isArray(value) && isObjectArray_(value)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (parseData_(headers, data, path, state, value[i], query, options, includeFunc)) {
        dataInserted = true;

        if (i > 0 && data[state.rowIndex]) {
          state.rowIndex++;
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (isObject_(value)) {
    for (key in value) {
      if (parseData_(headers, data, path + "/" + key, state, value[key], query, options, includeFunc)) {
        dataInserted = true; 
      }
    }
  } else if (!includeFunc || includeFunc(query, path, options)) {
    // Handle arrays containing only scalar values
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value = value.join(); 
    }

    // Insert new row if one doesn't already exist
    if (!data[state.rowIndex]) {
      data[state.rowIndex] = new Array();
    }

    // Add a new header if one doesn't exist
    if (!headers[path] && headers[path] != 0) {
      headers[path] = Object.keys(headers).length;
    }

    // Insert the data
    data[state.rowIndex][headers[path]] = value;
    dataInserted = true;
  }

  return dataInserted;
}

/** 
 * Parses the headers array and inserts it into the first row of the data array.
 */
function parseHeaders_(headers, data) {
  data[0] = new Array();

  for (key in headers) {
    data[0][headers[key]] = key;
  }
}

/** 
 * Applies the transform function for each element in the data array, going through each column of each row.
 */
function transformData_(data, options, transformFunc) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      transformFunc(data, i, j, options);
    }
  }
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given test value is an object; false otherwise.
 */
function isObject_(test) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(test) === '[object Object]';
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given test value is an array containing at least one object; false otherwise.
 */
function isObjectArray_(test) {
  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (isObject_(test[i])) {
      return true; 
    }
  }  

  return false;
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given query applies to the given path. 
 */
function includeXPath_(query, path, options) {
  if (!query) {
    return true; 
  } else if (Array.isArray(query)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
      if (applyXPathRule_(query[i], path, options)) {
        return true; 
      }
    }  
  } else {
    return applyXPathRule_(query, path, options);
  }

  return false; 
};

/** 
 * Returns true if the rule applies to the given path. 
 */
function applyXPathRule_(rule, path, options) {
  return path.indexOf(rule) == 0; 
}

/** 
 * By default, this function transforms the value at the given row & column so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
 *
 *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
 *     of the rows representing their parent elements.
 *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
 *   - Values in row 0 (headers) have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title 
*      case. 
 *
 * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
 *
 *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
 *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
 *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
 *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
 */
function defaultTransform_(data, row, column, options) {
  if (!data[row][column]) {
    if (row < 2 || hasOption_(options, "noInherit")) {
      data[row][column] = "";
    } else {
      data[row][column] = data[row-1][column];
    }
  } 

  if (!hasOption_(options, "rawHeaders") && row == 0) {
    if (column == 0 && data[row].length > 1) {
      removeCommonPrefixes_(data, row);  
    }

    data[row][column] = toTitleCase_(data[row][column].toString().replace(/[\/\_]/g, " "));
  }

  if (!hasOption_(options, "noTruncate") && data[row][column]) {
    data[row][column] = data[row][column].toString().substr(0, 256);
  }

  if (hasOption_(options, "debugLocation")) {
    data[row][column] = "[" + row + "," + column + "]" + data[row][column];
  }
}

/** 
 * If all the values in the given row share the same prefix, remove that prefix.
 */
function removeCommonPrefixes_(data, row) {
  var matchIndex = data[row][0].length;

  for (var i = 1; i < data[row].length; i++) {
    matchIndex = findEqualityEndpoint_(data[row][i-1], data[row][i], matchIndex);

    if (matchIndex == 0) {
      return;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < data[row].length; i++) {
    data[row][i] = data[row][i].substring(matchIndex, data[row][i].length);
  }
}

/** 
 * Locates the index where the two strings values stop being equal, stopping automatically at the stopAt index.
 */
function findEqualityEndpoint_(string1, string2, stopAt) {
  if (!string1 || !string2) {
    return -1; 
  }

  var maxEndpoint = Math.min(stopAt, string1.length, string2.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < maxEndpoint; i++) {
    if (string1.charAt(i) != string2.charAt(i)) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return maxEndpoint;
}


/** 
 * Converts the text to title case.
 */
function toTitleCase_(text) {
  if (text == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return text.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(word) { return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given set of options contains the given option.
 */
function hasOption_(options, option) {
  return options && options.indexOf(option) >= 0;
}

/** 
 * Parses the given string into an object, trimming any leading or trailing spaces from the keys.
 */
function parseToObject_(text) {
  var map     = new Object();
  var entries = (text != null && text.trim().length > 0) ? text.toString().split(",") : new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    addToMap_(map, entries[i]);  
  }

  return map;
}

/** 
 * Parses the given entry and adds it to the given map, trimming any leading or trailing spaces from the key.
 */
function addToMap_(map, entry) {
  var equalsIndex = entry.indexOf("=");  
  var key         = (equalsIndex != -1) ? entry.substring(0, equalsIndex) : entry;
  var value       = (key.length + 1 < entry.length) ? entry.substring(key.length + 1) : "";

  map[key.trim()] = value;
}

/** 
 * Returns the given value as a boolean.
 */
function toBool_(value) {
  return value == null ? false : (value.toString().toLowerCase() == "true" ? true : false);
}

/**
 * Converts the value for the given key in the given map to a bool.
 */
function convertToBool_(map, key) {
  if (map[key] != null) {
    map[key] = toBool_(map[key]);
  }  
}
```

Here is the Json

> {"DraftProjections":[{"playerId":"14","completions":"422","attempts":"640",
>   "passingYards":"4992","passingTD":"40","passingInt":"17","rushYards":"28","rushTD":"1","fantasyPoints":"335","displayName":"Drew
>   Brees","team":"NO"},{"playerId":"87","completions":"355","attempts":"526","passingYards":"4358","passingTD":"35","passingInt":"8","rushYards":"223","rushTD":"2","fantasyPoints":"332","displayName":"Aaron
>   Rodgers","team":"GB"},{"playerId":"1398","completions":"306","attempts":"501","passingYards":"3853","passingTD":"20","passingInt":"14","rushYards":"683","rushTD":"7","fantasyPoints":"316","displayName":"Cam
>   Newton","team":"CAR"},

Thank you for taking the time to view this.

Comment: here is a link to the complete JSON file http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/draft-projections/json/test/QB/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use someone else's script.

I've written you a custom, trimmed down one - this works.

Study how it works :) Be sure to label one of your sheets 'dataImport'

```
function urlDownload() {
  var dataImport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('dataImport');
  var apiPoint = "http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/draft-projections/json/test/QB";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiPoint);
  var response_json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
  var length = response_json.DraftProjections.length
  var a = [];
  for(i=0; i<length; i++){
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].playerId)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].completions)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].attempts)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 4, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].passingYards)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 5, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].passingTD)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 6, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].passingInt)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 7, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].rushYards)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 8, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].rushTD)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 9, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].fantasyPoints)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 10, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].displayName)
    dataImport.getRange(i+2, 11, 1, 1).setValue(response_json.DraftProjections[i].team)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I replaced into parseData_ function the conditional

```
if (i >0 && data[state.rowIndex]) {
```

for

```
if (data[state.rowIndex]) {
```

and work like a charm, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

How about using 'noTruncate' option to prevent trimming, as mentioned in the function description above?